# Efficient MongoDB query to split a field into an array

Tags: mongodb

This code splits the `nicknames` field in the `cities` collection into an array, but it's way to slow:

```
db.cities
  .find()
  .snapshot()
  .forEach(function(el) {
    el.nicknames = el.nicknames.split('->')
    db.cities.save(el)
  })
```

This code also splits the `nicknames` field in the `cities` collection into an array and it's much faster, but it temporarily causes the database size to double which crashes my database.

```
db.cities.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "nicknames": { "$split": [ "$nicknames", "->" ] } 
        }},
        { "$out": "cities" }
    ]
)
```

This seems like a trivial database task.  There has to be a better way... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take advantage of the **[`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)** method for efficient bulk updates. You can split up the update operation into batches for large collections.

Using the cursor from the aggregate operation (minus the last **`$out`** pipeline), you can compose the bulk update operations as:

```
let bulkUpdateOps = [];
const cursor = db.cities.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "nicknames": { "$split": [ "$nicknames", "->" ] } } }
]);

cursor.forEach(doc => {
    const { _id, nicknames } = doc;
    bulkUpdateOps.push({
        "updateOne": {
           "filter": { _id },
           "update": { "$set": { nicknames } },
           "upsert": true
        }
    });

    if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 1000) {
        db.cities.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);  
        bulkUpdateOps = [];                 
    }
}); 

if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) {
    db.cities.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
}
```